# The relationship between ε and δ in the (ε, δ)-definition of limitor

Tags: calculus, limits

Does the biggest δ also get smaller as ε is getting smaller ? why ?(exclude the case when f(x) is a constant function.)

P.S.I must declare I only have some basic knowledge of limit ,I started to learn calculus a few days ago .

Comment: What do you mean by biggest $\delta$?

Comment: no matter how small ϵ is, you can find countless  δ that can meet the requirement ,then there should be a biggest δ of them ,i.e. the  supremum of them .

Comment: That may be true in some cases, but I have a strong feeling that there are times when the set you speak of does not have a supremum.

Comment: I think you'd better give an example !

Comment: How about this one: Let $f(x)=\ln(x)$. Using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, you should be able to verify that given $\epsilon>0$, and $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ with $\delta = y(e^{\epsilon}-1)$, then $|\ln(x)-\ln(y)|<\epsilon$ anytime that $|x-y|<\delta$. But notice that $y$ can be as large as we want and it won't affect $\epsilon$. However, it will make $\delta$ as large as we want.

Comment: @graydad: I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something here, but isn't $y$ the point at which the limit is being evaluated?  In which case, wouldn't $y$ be held constant during the evaluation?  Therefore wouldn't the supremeum user1485853 mentions also be computed with $y$ held fixed?

Comment: I don't mean to suggest that there aren't cases in which the supremum is $\infty.$  There of course are.  A constant function is one example: $\sup\delta=\infty$ for any $\epsilon.$  Another is the $\sin$ function.  Suppose we apply the definition to the evaluation of $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x.$  For any $\epsilon>1,$ we have $\sup \delta=\infty.$  If you decrease $\epsilon$ from $3$ to $2,$ $\sup\delta$ does not decrease.  But clearly it can never increase, as is shown in Umberto P.'s answer.

Comment: @WillOrrick I was evaluating at $x$, which is why I thought it would be okay to let $y \to \infty$. But I definitely agree my example isn't air tight! :) I was trying to come up with an example for OP that wasn't the constant function. You have an argument for the sine function though?

Comment: I think you mean lnx→1 when x→e here, so $y$ cannot be too large . @Umberto P.’s proof is very convincing ,you can have a look .

Comment: @graydad: $\sin$ takes values in $[-1,1].$  So if $\epsilon>1$ then $\lvert\sin x-0\rvert<\epsilon$ for all $x.$

Comment: @Will Orrick  For every  ϵ>0 in the definition ,not just  ϵ>1.

Comment: If $\epsilon=0.5$ then $\lvert\sin x-0\rvert<\epsilon$ for $\lvert x-0\rvert<\frac{1}{6}\pi$ but not for all $x.$

Comment: @Will Orrick I don't know why you require it for all x ?

Comment: As I understood it, the question was to find an example of a non-constant function for which $\sup\delta$ was $\infty$ or, more generally, for which  $\sup\delta$ was constant rather than strictly decreasing (as a function of $\epsilon$).  The sine function provides such an example: $\sup\delta$ takes the constant value $\infty$ for all $\epsilon\in(1,\infty).$  For $\epsilon\in(0,1],$ $\sup\delta$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: if $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert<\epsilon$ for all $x,$ that's the same thing as $\Delta(\epsilon)=\infty.$  I wanted to show an example where the condition $\Delta(\epsilon)=\infty$ held over a range of $\epsilon$ values (to show that $\Delta(\epsilon)$ doesn't always decrease).  Equivalently, I wanted to exhibit a limit for which $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert<\epsilon$ held for all $\epsilon$ in a range of values with no restriction whatsoever on $x.$

Comment: In the comments to Umberto P.'s answer, I give an example where $\Delta(\epsilon)$ remains constant for all $\epsilon,$ not just for all $\epsilon$ in some range of values.  Certainly there are many such examples.  However, I think a better answer to your original question is that $\Delta(\epsilon)$ generally decreases with $\epsilon,$ but that there are examples where it remains constant rather than decreasing.

Comment: In $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments, there is no reason to have $\delta$ be as large as it can be.  People often let $\delta$ be smaller than it could be for the sake of a simpler mathematical argument.  Furthermore, if the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit holds, then it is correct to say that that $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x$ gets closer and closer to $a.$  That's because as $x$ gets closer and closer to $a,$ it will eventually be less than a distance of $\delta$ from $a.$  Beyond that point, $f(x)$ is guaranteed to be within $\epsilon$ of $L.$  No matter how small...

Comment: ... $\epsilon$ is, there will always be such a point beyond which $f(x)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $L.$  That's what the "there exists a $\delta$" business is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's quantify $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$.

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ so that $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Define $\Delta(\epsilon) = \sup \delta$, where the supremum (maybe $\infty$) is taken over all $\delta$ satisfying the quantified statement for a fixed $\epsilon$. $\Delta(\epsilon)$ is the "biggest $\delta$" you are talking about.

Suppose that $0 < \epsilon_1 < \epsilon_2$.

Let $\delta > 0$ be any value for which $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon_1$. Then in turn $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon_2$. Thus $\delta \le \Delta(\epsilon_2)$. Take the supremum over all such $\delta$ to conclude $$\Delta(\epsilon_1) \le \Delta(\epsilon_2).$$
That is, $0 < \epsilon_1 < \epsilon_2$ implies $\Delta(\epsilon_1) \le \Delta(\epsilon_2)$ so that the "biggest $\delta$" is nonincreasing as $\epsilon \searrow 0$.

Comment: I wonder when Δ(ϵ1)=Δ(ϵ2), does the function has to be a constant function ?why ?It would be better to give some proof .thanks in advance !

Comment: @user1485853: for the example of $\sin x$ in the comments to your post, we have $\Delta(2)=\Delta(3)=\Delta(1.1)=\ldots.$  This answers your question in the negative, since $\sin$ is not a constant function.

Comment: @Will Orrick but you require ϵ>1 there ,in the formal definition ,only require ϵ>0 ,i.e.it could be any positive real number .

Comment: Are you asking about the case where $\Delta(\epsilon_1)=\Delta(\epsilon_2)$ for all $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2>0,$ or the case where $\Delta(\epsilon_1)=\Delta(\epsilon_2)$ for some $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2>0?$  Your question didn't specify the former, so I came up with an example for the latter.

Comment: @user1485853: OK, here's an example of a non-constant function for which $\Delta(\epsilon)$ takes a finite constant value.  Let $f$ be defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}17 & x=5\\ 8 & x>5\text{ or }3<x<5\\ -39 & x=3\\ \frac{1}{x-3} & x<3.\end{cases}$$  Now $\lim_{x\to 5} f(x)=8,$ and if the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition is applied, we find that $\Delta(\epsilon)=2$ for all $\epsilon.$  Notice that the value of $f$ is constant in the set $(5-2,5+2)\setminus\{5\},$ which is necessary in order to have $\Delta(\epsilon)=2,$ but that it does not remain constant outside of this set.

Comment: Let $\Delta(\epsilon)=c$ for some positive constant $c.$  This implies that $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert<\epsilon$ for all $x\in (a-c,a+c)\setminus\{a\}.$  We claim that $f(x)=L$ for all $x\in(a-x,a+c)\setminus\{a\}.$  For suppose not.  Then there is some $x_1\in(a-c,a+c)\setminus\{0\}$ such that $f(x_1)=M\ne L.$  Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\lvert M-L\rvert.$  Then $\lvert f(x_1)-L\rvert=\lvert M-L\rvert=2\epsilon>\epsilon,$ contradicting the assumption that $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert<\epsilon$ whenever $x\in(a-c,a+c)\setminus\{0\}.$  So $f$ is constant in the interval $(a-c,a+c),$ except possibly at $a.$

Comment: Thanks for your great help !!! yes , f is constant in the interval (a−c,a+c), except possibly at a, and perhaps not in the entire domain.

as @Umberto P. said the "biggest δ" is nonincreasing as ϵ↘0 in this question .